# How to filter objects of certain type from [AnyObject] array

Tags: swift, filter, anyobject

Is it possible to filter an array of [AnyObject] to yield all elements of a given type, and none other?

I can do it if the type is known at compile time:

```
class MyClass1: CustomStringConvertible {

    var value: Int

    var description: String {
        return "MyClass1: \(value)"
    }

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class MyClass2: CustomStringConvertible {

    var value: Int

    var description: String {
        return "MyClass1: \(value)"
    }

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class MySubClass1: MyClass1 {
    override var description: String {
        return "MySubClass1: \(value)"
    }
}

let a1 = MySubClass1(1)
let a2 = MySubClass1(2)
let b1 = MyClass1(3)
let b2 = MyClass2(4)

let array: [AnyObject] = [a1, b1, a2, b2]

func getClass1ObjectsFromArray(_ array: [AnyObject]) -> [MyClass1] {
    return array.compactMap( { $0 as? MyClass1 })
}

func getSubClass1ObjectsFromArray(_ array: [AnyObject]) -> [MySubClass1] {
    return array.compactMap( { $0 as? MySubClass1 })
}

print(getClass1ObjectsFromArray(array))

print(getSubClass1ObjectsFromArray(array))
```

Prints:

```
[MySubClass1: 1, MyClass1: 3, MySubClass1: 2]
[MySubClass1: 1, MySubClass1: 2]
```

For every type I want to filter on, I had to write a separate function. This looks ugly to me, and will not work when the type to be selected for is only known at run time.

Question:

Is there a generic way to write such a function? Preferably something like:

```
func getObjectsOfType(_ type: TypeExpression, fromArray array: [AnyObject])
 -> [TypeExpression] {
     ... 
    }
```

Or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

I think you could use something like this...

```
let filteredArray = array.compactMap { $0 as? RequiredType }
```

This will filter the array and return a typed array containing only the type you want.

### Caveat

Having said that. In Swift you should be avoiding heterogeneous arrays where possible. Arrays should really only contain one type of item.

### A bit of code testing...

Tested in Playground...

```
let array: [Any] = [1, "hello", 3, 3.1415, "world"]

let filteredArray = array.compactMap { $0 as? String }

filteredArray
```

Output:

```
filteredArray = ["hello", "world"]
```

### Edit 1

You could also create a generic function something like this...

```
func filter<T>(array: [Any]) -> [T] {
    return array.compactMap { $0 as? T }
}

let filteredArray: [String] = filter(array: array)
```

This will then filter based on the type of the output array that you want.

I'm not sure what you mean by only knowing the type you want at run time. Can you give a more concrete example of what you mean?

### Edit 2

Another possibility is a generic function like this...

```
func filter<T>(array: [Any], byType typeObject: T) -> [T] {
    return array.compactMap { $0 as? T }
}

let filteredArray = filter(array: array, byType: "some string")
```

This uses the type information of the second parameter to filter the array by that type of item.

### Edit 3

If you don't like passing in an instance of the type then you can pass the type itself...

```
func filter<T>(array: [Any], byType typeObject: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return array.compactMap { $0 as? T }
}

let filteredArray = filter(array: array, byType: String.self)
```

But I'm not sure what more you're getting from this than just filtering by string in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works and makes the functions much more concise. But I still do need to write a separate function for each type I want to filter on, don't I? And what if the type is only known at run time? BTW, I do appreciate your warning about heterogeneous arrays, however this is firstly a question to further my understanding about what can and cannot be done in Swift.

Comment: I've added a couple of edits to show options of how to wrap the filter in a generic function that can infer the type to filter by.

Comment: If you're using `[AnyObject]`, you've almost certainly gone down a bad path. It falls within "what can be done in Swift," but it's outside what *should* be done in Swift. Almost all uses of `AnyObject` are fighting Swift and there are better solutions to the problem (usually an enum or a protocol).

Comment: @Fogmeister: Thanks a lot. Seems to go a long way towards what I want. I'll study it and let you know. As to your question what I mean by "not knowing the type at run time": I am aiming at writing a facility that can service many client instances who can (de)register objects with it, through it share those with other clients, search for objects registered by others, etc. In this scenario, I want to be able to service clients whatever the type of object is they want to register of search for. This is the short answer. The array was just an example, I envisage more complex data structures.

Comment: @Napier: thanks for the advice. Maybe my reply to Fogmeister makes it more clear why I am trying this. I agree that I seem to be fighting Swift here... coming from Python where this kind of thing is easy, so maybe thinking along the wrong lines. Any suggestions for exploring alternative approaches in Swift will be greatly appreciated.